# Mouse positions not given after trigger()

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

The problem is pretty straight forward:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(event){
    alert(
        "pageX: " + event.pageX +
        "\npageY: " + event.pageY
    );
});

$('#btn2').mouseout(function(e){
   $('#btn1').trigger('click');
});
```

The second button alerts undefined variables. Is there a way to  trigger the click event while passing the mouse positions?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h5fd/6/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#btn1').click(function(event){
    alert(
        "pageX: " + event.pageX + 
        "\npageY: " + event.pageY
    );
});

$('#btn2').click(function(e){
    $('#btn1').trigger(e);
});
```

Just pass the original `event object` that carries everything.

[**​DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6h5fd/4/).

Also you can create a custom `event object` and pass it as follows

```
$('#btn2').click(function(e){
    var evt={
        'type':'click',
        'pageX':e.pageX,
        'pageY':e.pageY
    };
    $('#btn1').trigger(evt);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6h5fd/7/).